# Validating Shopify webhook using nodejs and express

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

There are several [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61056350/1437782), but years old, and there is no documentation that I can find on how to use nodejs and express to validate a webhook [from Shopify for nodejs](https://shopify.dev/apps/webhooks/configuration/https#step-5-verify-the-webhook) in 2023. My issue, I know, is in getting the request body in the same format that Shopify used to create their hmac.

How do you correctly get the `req` body to create the local hash to compare against the hmac from Shopify?

```js
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import * as crypto from 'crypto'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'

const app = express()
app.use(cors({ origin: true }))

app.post('/order/create', bodyParser.text({ type: 'application/json' }), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const hmac = req.header('X-Shopify-Hmac-Sha256')
    const topic = req.header('X-Shopify-Topic')
    const shop = req.header('X-Shopify-Shop-Domain')
    const secret = await shopifySharedSecret()

    if (!secret) {
      throw Error('Check logs.')
    }

    const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret).update(req.body).digest('hex')

    if (hash !== hmac) {
      throw Error('hmac validation failed')
    }

    res.send({
      processed: true,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    res.send({})
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Needed to add an augment to access `req.rawBody`.

```js
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import * as crypto from 'crypto'

declare module 'http' {
  interface IncomingMessage {
    rawBody: unknown
  }
}

app.post('/ingest', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const hmac = req.header('X-Shopify-Hmac-Sha256')
    const topic = req.header('X-Shopify-Topic')
    const shop = req.header('X-Shopify-Shop-Domain')

    if (!hmac || !topic || !shop) {
      res.send({})
      return
    }

    const secret = await shopifySharedSecret()

    if (!secret) {
      throw Error('Check logs.')
    }

    const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret).update(String(req.rawBody)).digest('base64')

    if (hash !== hmac) {
      logger.info('hmac validation failed')
      res.send({})
      return
    }

    // Now can safely use webhook's req.body, which is json.

    res.send({})
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(403).send({})
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you use `digest('hex')` instead of `digest('base64')`.

The [Shopify docs](https://shopify.dev/apps/webhooks/configuration/https#step-5-verify-the-webhook) says :

> Each webhook request includes a base64-encoded X-Shopify-Hmac-SHA256
> header

So you need to use the same encoding.

Comment: I did try "hex" thinking the same thing that I might not be using correct encoding, but it turned out to be a little more complex for my use case. See my answer.